# Probability of observing the same individual in randomly selected groups?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose you observe $N$ individuals in $4$ years (the group of individuals is always the same). In each of those $4$ years, $Y$ individuals are selected are random (e.g., in each year, we select $10$ individuals at random). What is the probability that $1$ individual is in the randomly selected set $Y$ in at least $2$ years? What about $2$ individuals (or more generally, $M$ individuals)?

Comment: The complementary event is that the individuals sampled for years 1,2,3 and 4 do not have any individuals common.

Comment: @Grey first of all welcome! One question: when you talk about $2$ or $M$ individuals, are you referring to a specific group or any? 
Let me be clearer, do you want to calculate the Probability that Bob and Mike are selected each at least twice or any 2 individuals?

Comment: Hi Tommaso. Thanks for the welcome and apologies for the delayed response. I meant to ask about *any* two individuals. Thanks!